# Transformation of aestethic inputs in R and ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Is there a way to transform data in ggplot2 in the aes declaration of a geom?

I have a plot conceptually similar to this one:

```
test=data.frame("k"=rep(1:3,3),"ce"=rnorm(9),"comp"=as.factor(sort(rep(1:3,3))))
plot=ggplot(test,aes(y=ce,x=k))+geom_line(aes(lty=comp))
```

Suppose I would like to add a line calculated as the maximum of the values between the three `comp` for each `k` point, with only the `plot` object available. I have tried several options (e.g. using aggregate in the aes declaration, stat_function, etc.) but I could not find a way to make this work.

At the moment I am working around the problem by extracting the data frame with `ggplot_build`, but I would like to find a direct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment):

OK I see what you mean now - I should have read your question more carefully. You can achieve what you want using `stat_summary(...)`, which does not require access to the original data frame. It also solves the problem I describe below (!!).

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(k=rep(1:3,3),ce=rnorm(9),comp=factor(rep(1:3,each=3)))
plot <- ggplot(test,aes(y=ce,x=k))+geom_line(aes(lty=comp))
##
plot + stat_summary(fun.y=max, geom="line", col="red")
```

[image]

**Original Response** (Requires access to original df)

One unfortunate characteristic of `ggplot` is that aggregating functions (like `max, min, mean, sd, sum`, and so on) used in `aes(...)` operate on the whole dataset, not subgroups. So

```
plot + geom_line(aes(y=max(ce)))
```

will not work - you get the maximum of *all* `test$ce` vs. `k`, which is not useful.

One way around this, which is basically the same as @JLLagrange's answer (but doesn't use external libraries), is:

```
plot+geom_line(data=aggregate(ce~k,test,max),colour="red")
```

This creates a data frame dynamically aggregating ce by k using the max function.

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward! I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Is

```
require(plyr)
max.line = ddply(test, .(k), summarise, ce = max(ce))
plot = ggplot(test, aes(y=ce,x=k))
plot = plot + geom_line(aes(lty=comp))
plot = plot + geom_line(data=max.line, color='red')
```

something like what you want?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JLLagrange and jlhoward for your help. However both solutions require the access to the underlying data.frame, which I do not have. This is the workaround I am using, based on the previous example:

```
data=ggplot_build(plot)$data[[1]]
cemax=with(data,aggregate(y,by=list(x),max))
plot+geom_line(data=cemax,aes(x=Group.1,y=x),colour="green",alpha=.3,lwd=2)
```

This does not require direct access to the dataset, but to me it is a very inefficient and inelegant solution. Obviously if there is no other way to manipulate the data, I do not have much of a choice :)

Comment: This solution is directly copied from OP's question.